# VS Code: Deep Linking Extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on a VS code extension and would like to create a deep link which opens a file side-by-side with an extension. Let's take [the JSON editor extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nickdemayo.vscode-json-editor) as an example. Is it possible to create a link which opens a JSON file side-by-side with the editor window?

I'm aware of the following deep link pattern:

```
vscode://file/Users/d070350/test.process.json
```

Can I extend it somehow to open the JSON editor alongside the file?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to accomplish. Do you want to use the Webview from the JSON editor extension as a side editor and not show the raw JSON file?

Comment: I would like to show both using the split editor view. But I only know how to create a deep link for opening the file itself.

Comment: can't you call the `JSON Editor: Start JSON editor session` command (`vscode-json-editor.start`)